# How to access a custom parameter from the login page in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, login-page

I have a custom field along with "`j_username`" and "`j_password`" on my login.jsp, that I need to authenticate the user. I am using a CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to access the custom field as follows.

```
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String myCustomField= request.getParameter("myCustomField");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("CUSTOM_FIELD", myCustomField);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    }
}
```

I tried accessing the session in `loadByUsername` method of UserDetailsService class but I get an error. Here is the code for my custom UserDetailsService.

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException,  DataAccessException {

         ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
         HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
        User userObject = dbObject.retrieveUser(userName,myCustomParameter)
// code here to retrieve my user from the DB using the userName and myCustomParameter that was retrieved from login.jsp and put in the session. Get the custom parameter from the session here.

         if (userObject == null)
              throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

         return new AuthenticationUserDetails(userObject);
    }
```

Is there any way where I can access this custom parameter for authentication? Sending it through the session doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the session be created AFTER the authentication takes place.  So a new authenticated session might be created after your call to attemptAuthentication

Here's the spring doc on the Abstract class you're implementing

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#successfulAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29

You might be losing the session attribute by the time loadByUsername is called.

Comment: dardo : thanks for your reply. Yes that seems to be the problem as the session is created after authentication. Is there any way that I can access this new parameter in my `loadByUsername` method as I require that for retrieving the user object that is passed into  AuthenticationUserDetails for authentication.

Comment: You can really do whatever you want, if you want to put it in the Session, then retrieve it in the loadByUsername, use the org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder like...attrs = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(); attrs.getRequest().getSession(true);  Might not be the cleanest way of doing things, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact problem.

The problem appeared to be that the RequestAttributes was not bound to the current thread. To make it work, I had to explicitly bind it to the current thread.

In `CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, after the statement
    `request.getSession().setAttribute("CUSTOM_FIELD", myCustomField);`

Add:
    `RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));`

This worked for for me.